# How to reset dropdown value on hide?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to reset drop down value when it hides. I am hiding drop down when user reselect zero. 
Code for hiding is working sucessfully that is given below -:

```
if(child_num == 0){
    var e = document.getElementById("child1_age3");
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'none';

    var e = document.getElementById("child1_age2");
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'none';

    var e = document.getElementById("child1_age1");
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Code to reset dropdown value, it is not working.

```
// clear input on hide
document.getElementById('child1_age1').options.length = 0;
```

or

```
// clear input on hide
document.getElementById("child1_age1").selectedIndex = -1;
```

I tried with both of the way, but failed to reset. please suggest me how to reset this dropdown value.

Comment: Do you really mean clear the value, or not submit the value to the server? If it's the latter, can you just ignore the value at the server side?

Comment: What's with the `if/else` pairs doing exactly the same thing?

Comment: just I want to reset dropdown to value 0 or  index first when user click num of child 0

Comment: @Cerbrus same code is for different dropdown id

Comment: I got that much, but you really don't need the `if / else`, if the `if` clause does exactly the same as the `else` one. Just do `document.getElementById("some_id").style.display = 'none'`.

Comment: @Cerbrus there is complex conditional check, I have not posted complete one. Please answer a/c to question,  here  if else is not an issue, that is playing his role fine.

Comment: Can you put a fiddle or something for your issue ?

Comment: Please reproduce your issue here : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @RaghvendraKumar , I am reseting drop down value with two way posted in last of my question, which is not working please help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the below code to reset the drop down on selection of zero index:

HTML

```
<select id="dropDown">
    <option value="0">SELECT</option>
    <option value="1">CAT</option>
    <option value="2">DOG</option>
    <option value="3">COW</option> </select>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropDown").change(function(){
        var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
        //if the first element is selected again
        if(selectedIndex === 0){
            $("#dropDown").html("");
            $("#dropDown").append('<option value="0">SELECT</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it require jq first i think, please do it in plain js

Comment: Try the below Java Script code: document.getElementById("dropDown").addEventListener("change", onDropDownChange);

function onDropDownChange(){
    var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    if(selectedIndex === 0){
        document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML = '<option value="0">SELECT</option>'  ;      
    }
}

Comment: Ok value has been reseted I have used.document.getElementById("child1_age1").innerHTML = '<option value="0">0</option>' ;  but 0 is visible instead of hide.

Answer (score 0):

This may not quite answer the actual problem, but you *really* don't need those `if / else` statements if you're just setting the `display` to `'none'` any way.

This does **exactly** the same as the code in your question:

```
if(child_num == 0){
    document.getElementById("child1_age3").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("child1_age2").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("child1_age1").style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to set the drop down value :

```
var dropDownEle = document.getElementById("dropDownID").options;

    for (var i=0; i < dropDownEle.length; i++) 
    {
        if(dropDownEle[i].value == 'ValueYouWantToSelect');
            dropDownEle[i].selected=true;
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: still value is not reset on click of 0

Comment: have you used the code to reset before code used for hiding, if no please do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by reset you mean select the first <option> in the <select>:

```
var selectElement = document.querySelector("select");
selectElement.item(0).selected = true;
```

You can also use document.getElementById like so:

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById("child1_age3");
selectElement.item(0).selected = true;
```

The [item](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement.item)() function of a [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) takes an index value and will give you a single [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) representation of what  is at that index. HTMLOptionElement has a selected property, just set that to true.

Have a look here if you want to experiment with it: http://jsfiddle.net/kcguj6qh/

Comment: "select" is the selector for querying the DOM. You could retrieve this element however you want though, you could replace document.querySelector("select") with document.getElementById("child1_age3"); I've updated my example in my answer.